# Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue while developing Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Basically I have some javascript and I want to get a custom html template.

```
var content = $.get('localcontent.html', function() {

});
```

But I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///{path}/localcontent.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Where `{path}` is the path to folder containing both my javascript file and localcontent.html.

I have been ferociously Googling for some solution, but all I can seem to find is that Chrome doesn't let me read from local files because of a bunch of header crap. What do I do?

Comment: ...`$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('localcontent.html'),`...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried doing this but chrome.extension is null. I have my manifest file including the javascript file successfully because it is getting to the `getUrl` call, but says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getURL' of undefined". Am I missing something?

Comment: wt??? Have you installed your extension in chrome already??? Because it looks like that you don't. I mean why would javascript try to get a local file otherwise (`file:///`)

Comment: to do that go to `chrome://settings/extensionSettings` check developer mode and click on the open uncompressed extension button and select the folder in which the manifest file is.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ajax set of methods can speak HTTP, GET and POST, so you need to tell it to get the file from a server, giving it the URL for the server (the "path" part in the error message).

There is also a new HTML5 File API which may also be useful for your use case, http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-FileAPI-20091117/ .

Comment: no you don't need to, I developed a lot of chrome extensions already and it always worked without